# NSUserDefaults Values and SQLite Database after update an app in the Appstore

Tags: iphone, sqlite, sdk, app-store, nsuserdefaults

What happens with the `NSUserDefaults` values and the SQLite database after updating the application in the appstore?

Are they deleted or reseted or happens nothing with them?

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in the writeable documents folder (including user defaults and database file) of your apps sandbox will not be touched when the user installs the update from the app store. You may use these file unchanged after the update.